# addProximityAlert fails with API 17?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, android-location

I've been banging my head for hours trying to get `addProximityAlert()` to work on a device or the emulator.  As a last act of desperation, I tried using an API 8 emulator rather than my usual API 17, and suddenly things started working.  What is different between API 8 and API 17 that might be causing me issues?

My code is very straight forward:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
locationManager.addProximityAlert(2, 2, 100, -1, proximityIntent);

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), filter);
```

`ProximityIntentReceiver` just extends `BroadcastReceiver` and logs a message.  I'm using DDMS and the emulator to set my location to `(2, 2)`.

My manifest has permissions for coarse and fine location providers.  Like I said, this code works fine on API 8.

Comment: No, still no idea.  I ended up using the code from the location manager to implement my own proximity alert feature.